# Maya – Strokes on Live Mesh

Tags: python, api, maya, stroke, mel

I searched for tutorials on how to achieve that effect that I can draw strokes onto live surfaces via API like that:

[image]

Also, I looked up to search for examples inside the "**devkit**" that Maya offers, the hint got was I have to use the class "**mpxToolCommand**", but to my surprise, those examples which use that class **does not work with Maya 2020 because of the viewport 2.0** somehow.

I wish I could show some code but unfortunately, I actually don't know where to begin, does anyone have a little hint to guide me into the right direction?